# Is there an analog for ( Var in Array = Bool ) from Python in Haxe?

Tags: python-3.x, haxe

So in python you can check to see if there's an item within an array and it'll return a boolean value. Is there anything like that in Haxe?
For example, in Python:

```
>>>a = [1,2,3,5,7] 
>>>6 in a
false
```

Comment: http://api.haxe.org/Array.html#indexOf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Lambda.has()` or `arr.indexOf() != -1` to get a boolean value.

https://try.haxe.org/#638FD

```
using Lambda;

class Test {
    static function main() {
        var arr = [1,2,3,5,7];
        trace("arr");
        trace(arr);
        trace("");

        trace("arr.has(6)");
        trace(arr.has(6));
        trace("");

        trace("arr.indexOf(6) != -1");
        trace(arr.indexOf(6) != -1);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Lambda.has` is particularly useful to remember since it works with any `Iterator`, not just arrays.  You also don't need to statically extend using `Lambda`, `trace(Lambda.has(6)` will work as well if you don't want to add `using Lambda;`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `a.indexOf()`.

This will return `-1` if the element does not exist in the array or the index it was found at. There's also `lastIndexOf`, if you need to search in reverse.